# 2017 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

SharePoint Stack Exchange is scheduled for an election [next week, May 15th](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/election/3). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1415/2017-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, May 15th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at current.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election. That said, if I have concerns about any questions in this fashion, I will be sure to point this out in comments before the decision making time.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 6):

How would you improve the voting rate on the site?

---

Since the famous meta post [Are SharePoint.SE users lazy voters?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/are-sharepoint-se-users-lazy-voters) was asked back in 2013 I have a feeling the community have improved. Or my questions and answers have increased in quality, drawing more community votes.

Still, in comparison to other sites, we have a low voting/post ratio. How would you, once elected moderator, improve the voting rate on the site?

Comment: If you think about the meaning of "to moderate", influencing users in a specific direction might not be (and should not be) the job of a moderator.

Comment: @Jinxed I value your opinion, but I disagree. Mainly because we moderators should guide users to 1) Accept answers, 2) Upvote answers that was helpful and 3) [My answer on above mentioned question](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/a/858/6382)

Comment: Very well, but that does not change my feeling that moderaters should moderate, not influence. Too often I see moderators (aka administrators at other sites like Wikipedia) vastly exceeding their mandate in order to do something they _think_ might be their duty, but isn't and should not be.

Comment: But I read your entry in that "lazy voters" question and tried to add my few cents: Sharepoint is an extremly business-oriented, very closed product, which excludes many creative, privately interested users and therefore limits community a lot. The UX-people you mentioned are working in or just interested in a much more accessible area.
This is what makes all the difference in "style" and "community" between these Stackexchange-Sites. Should Microsoft release a "community"-version of Sharepoint, this would totally change.

Comment: I totally agree with @BennySkogberg . The guide's user to be active should be the main job for moderators. we face a big issue about this! we don't wait for more points.where our main goal is to help people and share our knowledge meanwhile we just need a kind of encouragement and appreciation that represented in accepting a correct answer or at least upvote it :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Comment: The last bullet-point mixes up content-related work and moderator-activities.