# Answered question in section "Unasnwered"

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Why question with answers appears in section "Unanswered Questions"? ([screenshot](https://content.screencast.com/users/Diezvai/folders/Jing/media/b33206ea-c472-4947-8e5f-647e2a74bcb1/2018-12-27_1607.png)). And after refreshing page a few times, that specific question is still visible/

I see that there is a filtering option "No Answers" but what is the point of section "Unanswered Questions" at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point of the Unanswered section is to highlight questions that doesn't have an accepted answer or no upvoted answers. It doesn't mean that there are no answers, only to highlight that none of the answers have been accepted by the user asking the question or upvoted by anyone.

On other *.SE sites, this works perfectly. In here, some users are a little lazy not voting up answers nor accepting the answer that helped them. There's a famous post on the topic where you can read more called [Are SharePoint.SE users lazy voters?](https://sharepoint.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/853/are-sharepoint-se-users-lazy-voters)